# Create Azure Media Services Asset for a blob already in it's associated storage account

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

Is it possible to create a Media Services asset and Sas Locator for video files that already exists in Azure Blob Storage? The storage account is the same one that is associated with that Media Services account. Assets.Create() creates a container for each video file. I have several hundred related video clips per container. I would like to create AccessPolicies for them and a locator so that the URL to the assets can be protected. The same AccessPolicies would apply to the entire container of video clips. This way I could delete the container and get rid of 100 blobs at once.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind the Asset.create()  will creat a container for each file because it might generate multiple files per Asset 
When you transcode the video using Media services the service will prepare a new file for optional streaming and or multi bitrate 
So you might end with 10 files per Asset 
If you do it with out a container you will end up with a crazy mass in your container

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Checkout the following blog post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-copying-existing-blob .  Each asset will have a container associated with it and that container can contain a bunch of video files.